# Yosemite, problems after Yosemite, Computer restarting everytime i log in

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro and a iMac. Recently I upgrade to Yosemite on both.

On my iMac, everything seems fine. But every time I try to log on to my MacBook Pro, it restarts and only the guest account with Safari only mode is available. This is a pain especially because i have to wait for the restart every time I want to use it. I am not great with computer so I need a clear answer. I have tried to repair disk but it doesnt work. Thanks.

Comment: If you know how, please provide us with a Console log.

Comment: I faced the same issue. In my case, the cause was an app that start at login. I suggest to prevent apps from start at login to confirm or discard it.